Axiom of Choice : Reasons behind using it or avoiding it?
I am a 1st year PhD student in Mathematics.
During my masters course in Ring theory, the proof of the result : Every commutative unital ring has a maximal ideal was done in the class. Every proof of it I saw uses Zorn's Lemma and while I was reading Topology book of James Munkres during my masters degree, I came to know that Zorn's Lemma was equivalent to Axiom of Choice (Chapter 1).
I was in 2nd year of my bachelors reading a textbook on Real Analysis( I forgot it's name, I borrowed it from the library) and the author wrote: Some mathematicians use Axiom of Choice while some mathematicians completely avoid it.
I studied about set theory in detail from James Munkres Topology's Chapter 1 while doing my topology course, had many questions but couldn't ask anyone as the instructor was not interested in teaching the course or taking any questions( I self studied using the help of couple of textbooks and a bit of internet).
I asked a professor during a seminar in which she used Axiom of Choice for a proof that why she used this axiom and her reply was : "Because it lets me prove interesting results" and no other explanation was given.

Question: Some mathematicians use Axiom of Choice and what is the reason given by them  why they use it? and Some mathematicians avoid the Axiom of Choice, what is the reason behind that?

Any reference for detailed discussion on this is most welcome.

We use it because it's a powerful axiom that lets you prove stuff, and we know that it cannot add a new contradiction to the system, so we might as well take it with us. Some people are suspicious of it, since some people are suspicious of things they didn't build themselves. Some people are rejecting much more than the axiom of choice. This all had been discussed in very great lengths both on this website and on [math.se] in the past 14 years or so.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/

Here's one way to think of it. Rewrite your question, replacing "set theory" with "group theory", and replacing "axiom of choice" with "commutativity". The study of groups that satisfy commutativity is very interesting. And the study of groups that satisfy noncommutativity is very interesting. People learn about both fields, people might do research in just one of them, and mathematics is all the richer for it. The same is true of the axioms of set theory with and without the axiom of choice.

Asaf, you give the extrinsic justification, but many people favor the intrinsic justification, holding that the axiom of choice expresses a fundamental truth about the nature of sets, and that is why they feel free to use it. At bottom, the view is that the axiom is a logical truth.

@LeeMosher There is one (sociological?) difference however: non-abelian groups appear very frequently, and the study of non-abelian groups is quantitatively comparable to that of abelian groups. However, most contemporary mathematicians accept the axiom of choice, and modern mathematics without AC is almost bare (or at least, kilometers behind the "front" of modern mathematics).
